# Wordpress user is able to login but can't find it in the database

Tags: wordpress, malware, wordpress-admin, wordpress-database

So, I have an admin user on Wordpress, I can login, I can post, update, install plugins, etc.
But when I try to find my user name, or email on the database wordpress is using (in wp-config file), I'm not able to locate it. and mine is not the only user I'm not able to find in the database.

Now,I got to this discovery, because our wordpress site was hacked not long ago, I'm going through the files, and I see some random code on the top of index.php or other files.

I clean and get rid of this code, and files too ! ( aindex.php, ajax-index.php. etc.)
At some point in the middle of the night, some files is creating this files, and inserting this random code again. SO I need to do this everyday in the morning, otherwise the wordpress admin doesn't work. Any insight on this too, will be very appreciate it.

Anyway, it is possible that whoever hacked the site, is making wordpress to store new users on an external database ?

Thanks, any help will be appreciate it.

Note I'm using: Wordfence, WP security, Cerber Security, Defender, iThemes Security to help scan the files.

Answer (score 0):

In relation to your first point, users are not stored in `wp-config.php`. They are stored in the database - you can access the database via your domain.com/phpmyadmin (depending on the database manager you're using).

Within the database tables you will find wp_users and wp_usermeta where the information you are looking for will be stored.

You can have a look at [this page](https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/beginners-guide-to-wordpress-database-management-with-phpmyadmin/) for some more information.

Comment: Right, the reason I mentioned wp-config, is because that's where the db name is configured, I did used Phpmyadmin to check wp-users table, maybe I didn't explained that part very well, but yes, I do know that no information is stored on that file, al least not other than configuration info. but thanks for the reply.